# Azure web role does not always show mobile view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an odd error. When I first deploy my Azure app I can view the mobile version of the site (Index.Mobile.cshtml). 15 minutes later I get the desktop view instead (Index.cshtml).

If I browse the website once every 10 minutes then I see the mobile version for as long as I want (tested 6 clicks over an hour). I then didn't click a link for 15 minutes, when I did I got the desktop version again.

If I restart IIS then the process repeats, I first get the mobile version, keep refreshing for 5 minutes and I correctly see the mobile version. Wait 15 minutes and I get the desktop version.

The same code running on a physical server stays correct and debugging locally works too.

The _ViewSwitcher correctly still says I'm on the mobile version but it's not using the Index.Mobile.cshtml version of the page.

I'm running ASP.NET MVC 4 RC.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: What is the difference between mobile and desktop version with your reference to Google/Microsoft CDN? as you are loading static files from CDN, how the links are used with mobile and desktop version. please explain.

Comment: Hi, what determines if the .Mobile.cshtml version of a page is shown or not? I don't think the JQuery.Mobile framework does that? I'm now thinking it's an IIS issue as restarting the app in IIS fixes the problem for 15 minutes until it breaks again.

For the CDN references I am just doing for example: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Not familiar with the version switcher, but it sounds like it is relying on a Session/Cookie that is expiring - doesn't really make sense, but it sure sounds like a familiar problem with those two item types expiring....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug to do with MVC4:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280?PendingVoteId=280